Quasar 2 / Vue 3: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function - top level await
I have a new Quasar 2 / Vue 3 app open in VSCode, created using the Quasar CLI and accepting all the defaults including using eslint.
I have NOT started the app (quasar dev).
Vitest is installed via the quasar ext add @quasar/testing-unit-vitest. The example tests work.
ie npm run test:unit - all tests pass.
Now, in my Vitest script I wanted to load a custom class that does some setup and am encountering the eslint error: Parsing error: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function which is strange because I am using node 18.18.0 and "top level awaits" are valid. More to the point, the test runs correctly after the "top level" async method runs. See code below using a bare-bones method to test the linting error.
However: I cannot launch my Quasar app because it chokes on the eslint error. I have tried all sorts of ways to disable the linting. One thing that does suppress this error is in .eslintrc.cjs to comment out the entry 'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',. As soon as I do that the error disappears (but others appear!) so it seems it is something in there?
Any suggestions on how I can suppress that error in order that I can start Quasar?
Thanks,
Murray
import { installQuasarPlugin } from '@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest';
import ExampleComponent from './demo/ExampleComponent.vue';

// === Added this custom section
import TestAwait from './testawait.js';
const testawait = new TestAwait();

// These don't suppress the error
/* eslint-disable */
// eslint-disable-next-line
await testawait.mytestAsync(); // <==== eslint error here
// === End custom section

installQuasarPlugin();

describe('example Component', () => {
  it('should mount component with todos', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(ExampleComponent, {
      props: {
        title: 'Hello',
        totalCount: 4,
        todos: [
          { id: 1, content: 'Hallo' },
          { id: 2, content: 'Hoi' },
        ],
      },
    });
    expect(wrapper.vm.clickCount).toBe(0);
    await wrapper.find('.q-item').trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.vm.clickCount).toBe(1);
  });
});


The class:
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('TestClass class instantiated');
  }

  async mytestAsync () {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log('mytestAsync() ran!');
  }
}

export default TestClass;


The result:


Can you post the eslint configuration?

Ok, after getting some sleep the answer was obvious!
In .eslintrc.cjs file exclude the tests folder by using the ignorePatterns so the test files are not linted:
module.exports = {
  // ...
 
  ignorePatterns: [
    '**/__tests__/'
  ],

  // ...
}

Fixed! And Quasar now starts up.
:-)

@Murrah's answer bypasses rather than solves the problem.
But this worked for me:
I had to switch to "es2022" as the build target in quasar.config.ts
build: {
    target: {
        browser: ["es2022"],
        node: "node18",
    },
}

But I couldn't get the following to work:
export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true //browsers can handle top-level-await features
    },
  }
})


No, I didn't try that. Can you expand on how / where one implements that code fragment, please?
